# Ethereum confirmation of transaction

Tags: transactions, confirmations

I did my first transaction to the wallet and now I'm waiting for confirmation completed. How long does it usually take to complete? As you can see, I'm waiting for about 3 hours and still not even one confirmation

[image]

Comment: have you looked up the transaction on a block explorer like [live.ether.camp](http://live.ether.camp) yet?

Comment: where can i find "blox index or any hash" ?

Comment: it's what you censored in your screenshot. But at this point I would simply rebroadcast the transaction.

Comment: Give a txid, because we can only guess now.